# How can I create a database in SQL workbench with existing code to then use it in R?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, create-table, mysql-error-1064

I'm completely new to SQL workbench so I apologize for my question that may sound stupid to you. I've downloaded a text file that contains code for an SQL Database from github and tried to create that database in SQL workbench with using the code from the textfile - and end up getting a lot of error messages. My goal is to create tables to then reuse them im R, or, export the tables as csv if possible. The code is really long, thats why I'm posting the direct link from github here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ghostery/whotracks.me/master/whotracksme/data/assets/trackerdb.sql

I created a database called "tracker" in mySQL workbench and then added
USE tracker;
in front of the code from github to get the tables from the code into it, but i run into errors such as

> USE tracker
> CREATE TABLE categories(
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
> name TEXT UNIQUE)  
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE categories(
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
> name TEXT UNIQUE)' at line 2   0.000 sec

I'd be very happy for your help... I'm completely lost. Thanks a lot in advance and greetings
Lena

Comment: In mysql every statement has to be terminated USE tracker isn't. Try USE tracker; then the rest of the code. Also identifiers should be qualified with backticks not double quotes. There may be other issues since this db does not look like mysql...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing the line separator (;) after Use tracker. Here is an example:

```
    Use test;

Create table testdata(
number int NOT NULL auto_increment,
PID varchar(30),
H_D_ID varchar(40),
lt decimal(12,10),
lit decimal(12,10),
timestampvarchar(40),
dte date,
tim varchar(20),
da varchar(3),
t_z varchar(30),
)ENGINE=InnoDB auto_increment=1;
```

You also do not need a MySql database to access information through R. You could use any of the read.table() R functions. Unless you are working with datasets to large for your hardware.

What is the original format of the documents that have the data?